# Android gps unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, gps

I am developing an Android gps-based application.

I have an activity which implements LocationListener and I have implemented logic in onLocationChanged method.

I want to make a Unit test which tests this activity. I want to loop an array of locations and send them to the activity where the onLocationChanged should fire.

I have read a couple of answers but none of them provided a complete solution.

I would be happy if anyone can explain me how to do it.

Regards,

Petar

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gavrikov.mocklocations&hl=en to mock location data. 
So you can have any "Mock location" application ruining in background and make sure you set fastest interval appropriately in your application to get location updates periodically.